# I am looking for a regular expression in python which will identify all the function bodies in a C file

Tags: python, c, regex

I am looking for a RE in python which will identify all the C function

I want to automate the insertion of some comments at the start of each function,
For example a function looks like

```
static my_struct1* alloc_mem (my_struct2* a)
{

...

}
```

I want to insert comment and make it look like

```
static my_struct1* alloc_mem (my_struct2* a)
{
/* my comment */
...

}
```

So I want to identify all the head (ending with `{`) of function bodies and insert comment there.

I tried below code:

```
def insert_comment():
    comment = "/* my comment */"
    pattern = r'[^(if|else|switch|for|if\s+|else\s+|switch\s+|for\s+)]\(.*\)(\s|\n)*\{'
    matches = list(re.finditer(pattern1, content))
    for match in matches:
        print('*****')
        print(match.group())

with open(filename, "r") as i:
        content = i.read()
        insert_comment()
```

But this is also matching `if` and `else` statements which have nested `(` expression.

For example,

```
if(MACRO(expa) && MACRO(expb)) {
```

Then the matched pattern will be

```
O(expb)) {
```

What might be a better RE to get start of function body?

Comment: Insert obligatory "wouldn't you prefer the right tool instead" comment here.

Comment: What is the right tool, yes i'd prefer that

Comment: [`pycparser`](https://pypi.org/project/pycparser/). You can find others if you google "python parse c"

Comment: C syntax is too complex to use a regular expression to match things like this.

Comment: Preprocessor abuse e.g. `#define begin {` will crush your regex, even if you did get it to work with simple C.

Comment: Automating adding a bunch of spaces and at the beginning of entering a function scoped body really is useless, why do it ?

Comment: @Barmar I was trying to use pycparser but it throws error when parsing files because the C file has many #include "abc/def.h", but these files are not present in the same directory. I just have the copy of the file I need to add the comments to
Is there a way I can use this library on a C file whose defined libraries aren't present

Comment: @sln I am a fresher at a company working on a large C project, what I want to do is add log macros to print func name and file name at the start of each function LOG_MACRO(__FUNC__, __FILE__) so that I can run the program and understand the function flow
I am not good at C, and only been coding in python so trying this method to understand this C project. All the numerous folders and C files makes it seem overwhelming
If you know of any better way to understand this C project, it would really be helpful... thanks

Comment: sounds like what you really need is a C debugger.

Comment: @erik258 Apparently the process created by this C program runs on multi-core env with each instance of this process running on each of the cores... and there is some heartbeat daemon which will reboot the OS if the process is unresponsive for a few seconds.
So I am unable to use gdb debugging on this program properly

Comment: You can run dynamic Code Coverage on your project and generate a report. Alternatively, you can run Code Metrics on your static source to determine complexity. Or you can do both. This is something that might be difficult to do as a custom project.

Comment: There are tools, like the [Understand editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Understand_(software)) that will generate call graphs, and allow you to easily find where a function is defined, and where it's called. You *will* need access to the header files.

Comment: I don't see why any of those are reasons you can't use a debugger.  However static code analysis as others have suggested, might be more convenient or useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by others, C syntax is too complex to analyze without
a dedicated parser in a strict sense.
As for your requirements, however, it looks some under/over detection
may be acceptable (harmless), because it will not cause defects to
the original source code just to insert comments.

Here is a simple code to start with to insert comments at your desired points
under limited conditions:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import regex

with open(filename) as f:
    s = f.read()
    m = regex.sub(r'\b(?:if|switch|for|while|until)\b(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(([A-Za-z_]\w*\s*\((?:[^()]+|(?2))*\))\s*{)', r'\1\n/* my comment */', s)
    print(m)
```

[Explanations]

- `regex` is a PyPi module with additional regex functionalities.
- `(?:if|switch|for|while|until)` is the reserved names which has
  a syntax similar to C functions (to be excluded).
- `\b(?:if|switch|for|while|until)\b(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` discards these matches.
- `(([A-Za-z_]\w*\s*\((?:[^()]+|(?2))*\))\s*{)` is a recursive regex which
  matches C function names with balanced parentheses.

**[Edit]**
If you are sure the macro names are all uppercase letters, you can exclude them by tweaking the regex as:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import regex

with open(filename) as f:
    s = f.read()
    m = regex.sub(r'\b(?:if|switch|for|while|until|[A-Z_]+)\b(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|(([A-Za-z_]\w*\s*\((?:[^()]+|(?2))*\))\s*{)', r'\1\n/* my comment */', s)
    print(m)
```

Input example:

```
static my_struct1* alloc_mem (my_struct2* a)
{ 
// function
}

some_function(foo) {
// function
}

if(MACRO(expa) && MACRO(expb)) {
// reserved word
}

TAILQ_FOREACH(entry, hent, next) {
// macro
}

while(true) {
// reserved word
}
```

Output:

```
static my_struct1* alloc_mem (my_struct2* a)
{
/* my comment */
// function
}

some_function(foo) {
/* my comment */
// function
}

if(MACRO(expa) && MACRO(expb)) {
// reserved word
}

TAILQ_FOREACH(entry, hent, next) {
// macro
}

while(true) {
// reserved word
}
```

[Explanation]

The regex `[A-Z_]+`, which matches the all uppercase letters, is appended to
the list of exclusion as:

```
(?:if|switch|for|while|until|[A-Z_]+)
```

Comment: Thanks this really helps, although it also cover's certain macro calls like 
TAILQ_FOREACH(entry, hent, next) {
It still works for all func calls

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Good to know it helps. Actually we cannot distinguish the macro from functions from syntax point of view. If we can set the operational rule, such as macro names should be all uppercase characters, we would be able to exclude them. Cheers.

Comment: What would be the regex if the macro names were always in caps... thanks

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've updated my answer accordingly in the \[Edit] section. BR.